# ON Duplicate Key update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the following code to Insert/update MySQL table but its not doing anything when duplicate record exists I used `ON Duplicate Key update`. the code  works great to insert but i want to update if description is differ from the source so i added this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = VALUES ('$pdesc')"` but it not inserting also not updating

```
mysqli_query($con,
    "INSERT INTO  table_name
    (STOCK_NO, PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION, SALES_DESCRIPTION, itemId, itype, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, uOfM, uConvFact, poUOfM, lead, suplId, suplProdCode, minLvl, maxLvl, ordLvl, ordQty, unitWgt, sales, bomRev,  makebuy) VALUES
    ('{$itemid}', '{$pdesc}', '{$sdesc}', '{$itemId}', '{$itype}', '{$itemdsc}', '{$uOfM}', '{$uConvFact}', '{$poUOfM}', '{$lead}', '{$supplId}', '{$suplProdCode}', '{$minLvl}', '{$maxLvl}', '{$ordLvl}', '{$ordQty}', '{$unitWgt}', '{$sales}', '{$bomRev}', '{$makebuy}')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = VALUES ('$pdesc')"
);
```

//STOCK_NO is the primary Key

Comment: Shouldn't `VALUES ('$pdesc')` be `VALUES (PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION)`?

Comment: @JonStirling But the `PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION` is the field in destination table i want to update

Comment: And? You want to use the value from the INSERT for that column. `VALUES()` doesn't take a random string, it takes a column name. Have a read of [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: @JonStirling still not updating

Comment: @user6305775 but $pdesc is not a _field_ in the inserted data, it is a _value_.

Comment: @Uueerdo yes, $pdesc is not a field in the inserted table it is variable `$pdesc = $data2['fields']['PURCHASE DESCRIPTION'];`

Comment: @user6305775 Update your code to what you've updated with that change, Then. please have a look at [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if you're getting SQL errors. You're open to SQL injection attacks, so I wonder if that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: It should either be `PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = '$pdesc'` or `PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = VALUES(PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION)`

Comment: @barmar  that makes sense I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is incorrect. Take a look:

```
mysqli_query($con,
"INSERT INTO  table_name
(STOCK_NO, PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION, SALES_DESCRIPTION, itemId, itype, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, uOfM, uConvFact, poUOfM, lead, suplId, suplProdCode, minLvl, maxLvl, ordLvl, ordQty, unitWgt, sales, bomRev,  makebuy) VALUES
('{$itemid}', '{$pdesc}', '{$sdesc}', '{$itemId}', '{$itype}', '{$itemdsc}', '{$uOfM}', '{$uConvFact}', '{$poUOfM}', '{$lead}', '{$supplId}', '{$suplProdCode}', '{$minLvl}', '{$maxLvl}', '{$ordLvl}', '{$ordQty}', '{$unitWgt}', '{$sales}', '{$bomRev}', '{$makebuy}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 

-- HERE --
UPDATE PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = '{$pdesc}' 
");
```

Another option is `UPDATE PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION = VALUES(PURCHASE_DESCRIPTION)`

You can read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html